# Insert each table record into 1 column

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server so please bear with me.

I am trying to write a stored procedure that inserts all of the records into one single column in a temporary table.

Table#1

```
column1       column2       column3
-------       -------       -------
record1       record2       record3
record4       record5       record6
```

Table#2 (EDITED)

```
column1    original_field    data_type
-------    --------------    ---------
record1       column1         nvarchar
record2       column2         nvarchar
record3       column3         nvarchar
record4       column1         nvarchar
record5       column2         nvarchar
record6       column3         nvarchar
```

Now my problem is that the table#1 is not static so the number of columns may change per execution of the procedure.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of columns that procedure can return ?

Comment: 1 column. The procedure is supposed to return a XML string. But what I am currently trying to do is merge all these records together to a temporary table.

Comment: @JoshuaPena so you want to know the code on how to merge all the records into one table?

Comment: Thats not my question. Since you have mentioned this "*the number of columns may change per execution*" Do you know the maximum number of columns that procedure can return ?

Comment: @Pரதீப் No, I don't know yet. I am currently working on tables with 4-25 columns. Sorry I am new to SQL server so I'm still confused.

Comment: @Mr.J Yes, that's my question. But without specifying the column names on my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot to be taken by the likes of you, but here is one solution.

I suggest using `cursors` for your problem.

`Cursors` are basically the while loop of SQL.

This example also uses the principle of dynamic SQL, you may want to research about them.

Please change the name of `testtb1` to the column name of the table you want to get the information.

Please also change the name of `testDB2` to the table where you want to put the data, and `newcol1` to the name of the column of the table `testDB2`, the column where you want to insert the collected data.

```
declare @TSQL as nvarchar(max)
declare @colname as nvarchar(50)
declare @cursor CURSOR
SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR 
(select [name] from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id  from sys.tables where name = 'testtb1'))


OPEN @cursor

FETCH NEXT

FROM @cursor INTO @colname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    set @TSQL = 'insert into testDB2 (newcol1)
    select '+@colname+' from testtb1'

    exec sp_executesql @TSQL, N'@colname nvarchar(50)', @colname
FETCH NEXT

FROM @cursor INTO @colName
END

CLOSE @cursor
DEALLOCATE @cursor
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly for me.